# Does SafeNet Token and Openvpn work on 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, openvpn

Does anybody have a way to make Openvpn work on Oneiric with a SafeNet token ?

I have install properly the token : http://www.jlaundry.com/2011/aladdin-etoken-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot-amd64/

it work, but when I try to use openvpn with that, it don't want to connect.

it can identify himself with the token,

any body have an idea for that ?

my other try was to install into a boostrap "lucid", install the drivers, use the vpn, 
I have mount with bind, the /etc/resolvconf and when I connect myself into the boostrap, it install the network properly in the host.

but the subsystem lock the token, so I can't use it in the host.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to make it work ! at least token work fine for everything now :

http://sck.to/X8 (little tutorial).

Tell me if it's ok for you.

Comment: The link is broken